# Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "uuid", (class *.CustomerDto), not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, uuid, jackson-databind

Migrating to Spring boot 3 I am stuck with this error on my automated integration tests, full stack trace below. I did a couple things related that might have to do with the problem:

- Jackson-databind was throwing some problems (`NoClassDefFound javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement`) so I updated it to the latest version and added dependency to some `jakarta.xml.bind-api` success.
- The tests have not been modified, pretty much it consumes one of my endpoints succesfully but then fails mapping the result back in the test.
- I tried: `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);` but no luck there.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "uuid" (class *.CustomerDto), not marked as ignorable (42 known properties: ..., "providerId", ...])
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: *.CustomerDto["uuid"])
 at io.restassured.internal.path.json.mapping.JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.java:30)
    at io.restassured.path.json.mapping.JsonPathObjectDeserializer$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.deserialize(Jackson2Mapper.groovy:58)
    at io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.parseWithJackson2(ObjectMapping.groovy:254)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$parseWithJackson2$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:240)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.deserialize(ObjectMapping.groovy:56)
    at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:229)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:169)
    at *.RestUtils.post(RestUtils.java:65)
    at *.InstallationControllerIntegrationTest.setUp(InstallationControllerIntegrationTest.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:78)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$23(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:505)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Actual code:

```
    ...
            customerId = restUtils
                    .post(customersUrl, customer, CustomerDto.class)
                    .getId();
    ...
```

```
    <T> T post(String url, Object dto, Class<T> type) {
        try {
            return RestAssured
                    .given()
                    .contentType(JSON)
                    .body(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto))
                    .when()
                    .post(url)
                    .as(type);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            fail(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class CustomerDto {
        private String id;
    ...
        private UUID providerId;
    
    ...
    
    }
```

PD; some values have been masked

Comment: The error means that Jackson is looking for a field named `uuid` in class `CustomerDto`, but that class does not have a field with that name. I see in your code that it does have a field of type `UUID`, but it's named `providerId` instead of `uuid`. Rename the field, or add a `@JsonProperty("uuid")` annotation to the field, or change your JSON (use the name `providerId` instead of `uuid` in the JSON).

Comment: why is it looking for a field called uuid?

Comment: Probably because the JSON that you are trying to parse but that you did not show us, contains a field named `uuid`. Something like this: `{ "uuid": "....", .... }`

Comment: You are right, it is because it is not returning the object expected but an exception... Thank you very much